How can I parameterize a build stage in dockerfile with multiple sets of arguments in a single build operation?
Lets say you had a Dockerfile that was like this:
FROM base AS build-project-a
RUN /src-a/build.sh # Builds to /output

FROM base AS build-project-b
RUN /src-b/build.sh # Builds to /output

FROM base AS run-both
COPY --from=build-project-a /output/ /build-a
COPY --from=build-project-b /output/ /build-b

Is there anyway to parameterize a stage such that you could have multiple resulting images for that stage depending on the parameters given?  Or in other words, is there a syntax like the following that would be equivalent to the more explicit Dockerfile above?
FROM base AS build-project
RUN ${SRC_DIR}/build.sh # Builds to /output

FROM base AS run-both
COPY --from=build-project-a --build-arg=SRC_DIR=/src-a /output/ /build-a
COPY --from=build-project-b --build-arg=SRC_DIR=/src-b /output/ /build-b

Is something like this possible? if so, then how?
This may seem like a non-problem but in my non-simplified case, there is some very similar stages that have many steps in them that aren't easily refactored to a helper script.  And while a helper script may reduce the number of lines in the Dockerfile, it does sacrifice the ability to do caching in steps (if you combined multiple runs into the script). Also lots of things can't be put into a script, like buildkit parameters passed to RUN and also COPY steps.  It has also been suggested in the comments below that this could be done as separate build operations, but that breaks parallelism

Are you looking for build args? Otherwise, I'd suggest looking into environment variables.

@a2k42 are you able to specify different sets of build args or environment variables to the same stage resulting in multiple images being built for the same stage?

if I've understood your question, this sounds like you want to script a loop which call the docker command with the different arguments. Each loop would pass in a different ARG . I don't know of a built in way of passing in a list and having it automatically loop through it if that is what you were after. If you're using docker compose you could enumerate each variant as a separate service. If you then want to use multiple build stages in the same final image, then you would probably want that in a different file (that you don't loop through).
